# Are unaligned LDRH/STRH supported on Cortex M3/M0?

Tags: arm, assembly, cortex-m3, cortex-m, cortex-m0

Can all Cortex M0/M3 cores do this?

```
LDRH r0, [0x8001]
```

[This](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15414.html) would suggest yes but I don't see anything specific about Cortex-M cores.

Answer (score 1):

1) As the Cortex-M [instruction set doc](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/BABJGHFJ.html) suggests, the construct in your example does not comply with the syntax. The second operand should be a register with optional immediate offset.

2) As the [instruction restrictions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/BABJGHFJ.html) state, the computed address should be divisible by the number of bytes in the transaction. In your case it's a half word, therefore divisible by two.

3) Generally (for Cortex-M0), [this page](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/BABFAIGG.html) is stating that:

> An aligned access is an operation where a word-aligned address is used
>   for a word, or multiple word access, or where a halfword-aligned
>   address is used for a halfword access. Byte accesses are always
>   aligned. There is no support for unaligned accesses on the Cortex-M0
>   processor. Any attempt to perform an unaligned memory access operation
>   results in a HardFault exception.

Comment: thanks for the link, looks like it is posible on the m3 http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/BABFAIGG.html